# can't understand how redis works with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm new on **redis** and i find that learning redis basics is very easy, but when i try to understand how i can use it with rails, it become flow and i can't find any good tutoriel which explains steps from scratch , for example i find code like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # follow a user
   def follow!(user)
     $redis.multi do
       $redis.sadd(self.redis_key(:following), user.id)
       $redis.sadd(user.redis_key(:followers), self.id)
     end
   end

  # unfollow a user
  def unfollow!(user)
    $redis.multi do
      $redis.srem(self.redis_key(:following), user.id)
      $redis.srem(user.redis_key(:followers), self.id)
    end
  end
```

but with this example, no other example show how to use `follow` method, what is the **object** i need pass to this method (is this object from a relational database ? or what )  etc ...

all examples i find in my search are incomplete, and this rend redis not easy at all when we decide to use it with rails  !

I also find that the use of redis is at the model that inherits from ActiveRecord, I can not understand: if redis is used in the majority of cases with a relational database or alone, and what is the way most used, and how exactly ?

i know that my question is vast but what i search is how use redis and rails together, also if you have a good resource for me, i will very appreciate that. thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> no other example show how to use follow method, what is the object i need pass to this method (is this object from a relational database ? or what ) etc ...

the users are ActiveRecord objects -- your users of your system.

```
friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
current_user.follow! friend
```

Usually, Redis is used as a secondary datastore. The regular user data, customer data, etc, is stored in Postgres or MySQL, and data that is redis-specific is stored in redis.

In [RailsCasts 399 on autocomplete](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms), Ryan shows how to use Redis to compliment the book store as a search engine only. He uses `$redis.zrevrange` and `$redis.zincrby`

Comment: what is the advantage here if i store ids of user un followers in redis ? so at the end I will extract their information from mysql/postgres !!

Comment: The advantage is a near constant time with pulling the list of people you follow. With millions of rows, this query will take a long time in a standard database.

Comment: yes sorry i forget to do this , you are the only one was answered my question and i think your answer is the best :) thank you, just if you can explain me what is "redis_key" function do ? as you can see in example "self.redis_key(:following)" , thank you

Comment: Check http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html. it creates "user:#{self.id}:#{str}".. so the key would be user:56:following and it would add the friend's user ID to that key's array.

Comment: ok thank you, i will research for other resources if exists, and why not if you create a clear blog post about this subject it will be helpful for lot of people like me :D